# K8s: what is the difference between Security Context and Security Policy?

Tags: kubernetes

Looking into Kubernetes documentation:

- [Pod Security Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)
- [Pod Security Context](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/)

Mmmm... aren't eventually they doing the same? What is the difference?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have no idea why folks are down-voting this question, it's spot on and actually we've got our docs to blame and not the OP. OK, here goes:

The pod security context (which is preceded by and largely based on OpenShift [Security Context Constraints](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/manage_scc.html)) allows you (as a developer?) to define runtime restrictions and/or settings on a per-pod basis.

But how do you enforce this? How do you make sure that folks are actually defining the constraints? That's where pod security policies (PSP) come into play: as a cluster or namespace admin you can define and enforce those security context-related policies using PSPs. See also the [Kubernetes Security](https://kubernetes-security.info/) book for more details.

Comment: Thank you, I have no idea either why the down-vote... About your answer: from documentation, at least as I can understand, both (policy or context) can be used to apply restrictions per-pod basis... Thank you for pointing me to the book.

Comment: You're welcome, and again: PSPs are policy resources and the enforcement is through the admission controller https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/#enabling-pod-security-policies … 

Also, if you're happy with the answer, suggest you accept as the correct one ;)

Comment: nice asnwer , but , can we do PSP as namespace admin? I dont see we can define pod security policy on namespace level only? when i list api-resoureces --namespaced , i dont see psp there , i think it needs to be defined on cluster level and then made available to namespaces?

Comment: Naturally it's available on the namespace level, if you have the permissions to create them.